# Multiple Dbset/entity modification with single call to SaveChanges()

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

I am working on a .NET Core Web API which needs to interact using EF Core 5.0.2 with an Azure SQL database.

I have different repository methods where I am interacting with `DbContext` to add/edit/delete records for different `DbSet`.

For example:

```
UserRepository.AddUser(userdata);
```

Implementation of AddUser is like this,

```
ourDbContext.UserTable.AddAsync(userdata);
```

So in user service method, am calling different repository method sequentially and none of those methods call `ourDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` individually. A single call to `SaveChanges` is present after all the repository methods calls which is acting like a unit of work pattern for all the calls as single transaction.

Example:

```
UserRepository.AddUser(userdata);
ActivityRepository.AddActivity("New User got added");
ourDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

So my question is: if any saving changes to any of the tables/entities fails, will the previous successful tables change will be rolled back?

For example, suppose this operation

```
UserRepository.AddUser(userdata);
```

was successful and the new user record was added to the User table.

But this was not successful:

```
ActivityRepository.AddActivity("New User got added");
```

So no activity record was added to the `Activity` table.

Will `SaveChangesAsync()` be able to handle this situation automatically and will roll back User table new changes as well?

If not are we supposed to wrap the above codes with transaction scope? Or what is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: A DbContext is a *multi-entity* Unit-of-Work. Having multiple "repositories" like this breaks this. Besides, classes with just CRUD methods are [Data Access Objects](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton), not repositories. A real repository on top of DbContext would abstract operations at a *higher* level than a single entity. Eg retrieving a customer's order, adding a new item and updating the customer's bonus points before calling `SaveChanges` to save *all* changes at once

Answer (score 1):

Briefly how `DbContext's` Change Tracker works:

- You load entities: ChangeTracker remembers current values of all loaded entities (except you use `AsNoTracking()`)
- You have modified loaded entities, delete, add new.
- You call `SaveChanges`: ChangeTracker starts searching which objects are changed since last load by comparing with previous values.
- DML SQL is generated and everything saved in one SQL statement or in several statements in Transaction.

So, if you have one `DbContext` for each repository, you do not need to worry about rollbacking, just do not call `SaveChanges()`. For sure for restart process, you have to recreate `DbContext` because it contains not needed state.

Comment: Using different DbContext per "repository" would break this though. UoW functionality would only work if all repositories used the same DbContext instance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have mentioned that, isn't?

Comment: I have checked the instance of DbContext in all those Data Access Object classes is equal to the DbContext instance used as UoW SaveChanges()(i.e. ourDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()).So calling all those individual entity modification methods with a single SaveChanges() at the end should be considered as a single transaction right?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you wrote the opposite `if you have one DbContext for each repository, you do not need to worry about rollbacking, just do not call SaveChanges()`. With one DbContext per repository you *lose* the ability to rollback all changes. If you need to make 5 `SaveChanges` calls and the last fails, you'd need an external transaction to roll all of them back

Comment: @RiktimMondal yes, but the very fact you had to make that check is a very, very strong warning *against* your current design. Clearly, those "repositories" can't work independently. For this particular use case/scenario/bounded context, you need a *single* repository that combines all of them.A DbContext isn't a model of the database. You can and *should* have multiple DbContexts with entities tailored to specific scenarios

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this isn't nitpicking. There way, way too many SO questions from people that blindly copied some "generic repo" recipe without knowing what it's for only because it's a "best practice". Then add a transaction on top, get into deadlocks and post an SO question. After blaming the database of course